# Rsocket Server exception: No handler for destination '' (destination does not pass from client to server)

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty, project-reactor, rsocket

I wrote a little demo for RSocket message

The problem is that I am unable to access the `Rsocket` endpoint,
I get the following exception from the server:

The Client-side:
**configuration:**

```java
@Bean
RSocket rSocket() {
    return RSocketFactory.connect()
            .mimeType(MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .frameDecoder(PayloadDecoder.ZERO_COPY)
            .transport(TcpClientTransport.create(new InetSocketAddress(7500)))
            .start()
            .block();
}

@Bean
RSocketRequester requester(RSocketStrategies strategies) {
    return RSocketRequester.wrap(rSocket(), MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON, strategies);
}
```

**controller:**

```java
private final RSocketRequester requester;

@GetMapping("/greet/{name}")
public Publisher<GreetingsResponse> greet(@PathVariable String name) {
    return requester
            .route("hello")
            .data(new GreetingsRequest(name))
            .retrieveMono(GreetingsResponse.class);
}
```

The server side(using spring Rsocket):
**yml:**

```
spring:
  rsocket:
    server:
      port: 7500
      transport: tcp
  main:
    lazy-initialization: true
```

**configuration:**

```java
@MessageMapping("hello")
Mono<GreetingsResponse> greet(GreetingsRequest request) {
    return Mono.just(new GreetingsResponse("Hello " + request.getName() + " @ " + Instant.now()));
}
```

I am pretty sure it has something to do with the new `wrap` function, `RSocketRequester.wrap` 
as it accepts a new parameter `metadataMimeType`, I set it to application/Json,
but it does not seems to work

**stackTrace:**

> org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: No handler for
>   destination ''    at
>   org.springframework.messaging.rsocket.annotation.support.RSocketMessageHandler.handleNoMatch(RSocketMessageHandler.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.reactive.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.getHandlerMethod(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:445)
>     at
>   org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.reactive.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:417)
>     at
>   org.springframework.messaging.rsocket.annotation.support.MessagingRSocket.lambda$handleAndReply$4(MessagingRSocket.java:173)
>     at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)    at
>   reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3920)     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatArray.java:207)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray.subscribe(FluxConcatArray.java:80)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoFromFluxOperator.subscribe(MonoFromFluxOperator.java:74)
>     at
>   io.rsocket.RSocketResponder.handleRequestResponse(RSocketResponder.java:386)
>     at io.rsocket.RSocketResponder.handleFrame(RSocketResponder.java:298)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:160)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:238)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$UnicastGroupedFlux.drainRegular(FluxGroupBy.java:554)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$UnicastGroupedFlux.drain(FluxGroupBy.java:630)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$UnicastGroupedFlux.subscribe(FluxGroupBy.java:696)
>     at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8000)    at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:184)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1582)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.onNext(MonoProcessor.java:316)
>     at
>   io.rsocket.internal.ClientServerInputMultiplexer.lambda$new$1(ClientServerInputMultiplexer.java:116)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:160)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$GroupByMain.drainLoop(FluxGroupBy.java:380)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$GroupByMain.drain(FluxGroupBy.java:316)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$GroupByMain.onNext(FluxGroupBy.java:201)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114)
>     at
>   reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:206)
>     at
>   reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:322)
>     at
>   reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:342)
>     at
>   reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:91)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
>     at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:328)
>     at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:302)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1421)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:697)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:632)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:549)
>     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:511)     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Which spring version are you using?
I had a same issue and I solved it by changing spring-boot-starter-parent 2.2.0.M3.

Here is my source
https://github.com/han1448/spring-rsocket-example

---

Added.

I solved this issue. You need to change mimeType to `message/x.rsocket.routing.v0`.
You can get this mimeType from `MetadataExtractor.ROUTING`.

```
@Bean
RSocket rSocket() {
    return RSocketFactory.connect()
            .mimeType(MetadataExtractor.ROUTING.toString(), MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .frameDecoder(PayloadDecoder.ZERO_COPY)
            .transport(TcpClientTransport.create(new InetSocketAddress(7500)))
            .start()
            .block();
}

@Bean
RSocketRequester requester(RSocketStrategies strategies) {
    return RSocketRequester.wrap(rSocket(), MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON, MetadataExtractor.ROUTING, strategies);
}
```

Comment: This completely fixed my problem too!  Unfortunately it no longer compiles under M6

Comment: However I did manage to use the RSocketRequester.Builder instead: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.M6/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-rsocket-requester

Answer (score 4):

For `RSocketRequester`, the method name from **create** to **wrap**, and then add third param. So, I think it's not stable now.

What's my choice is to use builder method, as the below shown.

```java
@Bean
RSocketRequester rSocketRequester(RSocketStrategies strategies) {
    InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(clientConfigProp.getHost(), clientConfigProp.getPort());
    log.info("RSocket server address={}", address);
    return RSocketRequester.builder()
        .rsocketFactory(factory -> factory
            .dataMimeType(MimeTypeUtils.ALL_VALUE)
            .frameDecoder(PayloadDecoder.ZERO_COPY))
        .rsocketStrategies(strategies)
        .connect(TcpClientTransport.create(address))
        .retry().block();
}
```