# @GetMapping and RSocketServer with spring-boot-starter-rsocket

Tags: java, spring-boot, rsocket

Was trying out RSocket Request/Response as specified in section 4 of https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-rsocket. So there is a RSocketServer autoconfigured and listening at port 7000. Unable to connect to the method annotated with `@GetMapping` when hitting the same from browser

```
@RestController
public class MarketDataRestController {

    private final RSocketRequester rSocketRequester;

    public MarketDataRestController(RSocketRequester rSocketRequester) {
        this.rSocketRequester = rSocketRequester;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/current/{stock}")
    public Publisher<MarketData> current(@PathVariable("stock") String stock) {
        return rSocketRequester
          .route("currentMarketData")
          .data(new MarketDataRequest(stock))
          .retrieveMono(MarketData.class);
    }
}
```

Expecting to be able to connect to the `current()` of the class `MarketDataRestController` annotated with `@GetMapping` when requesting the same from browser, say e.g.: http://localhost:7000/current/APPLE.
Not sure how to connect to the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use [@RequestMapping](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-rsocket)  with sockets, use `@MessageMapping` instead:

> instead of @RequestMapping or @GetMapping annotations like in Spring MVC, we will use the @MessageMapping annotation:
>
> ```
> @Controller
> public class MarketDataRSocketController {
> private final MarketDataRepository marketDataRepository;
> public MarketDataRSocketController(MarketDataRepository marketDataRepository) {
>     this.marketDataRepository = marketDataRepository;
> }
> @MessageMapping("currentMarketData")
> public Mono<MarketData> currentMarketData(MarketDataRequest marketDataRequest) {
>     return marketDataRepository.getOne(marketDataRequest.getStock());
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My understanding is that the MessageMapping handler method currentMarketData() in MarketDataRSocketController is expected to be called from current() in MarketDataRestController. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Separated out the REST client to a web-app of it's own and invoked the @MessageMapping handler method in the RSocket Server, but getting org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: No handler for destination ''

Comment: The above mentioned issue was resolved by the usage of RSocketRequester.Builder to obtain a RSocketRequester as mentioned in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.M6/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-rsocket-requester . Thanks to  Trisha Gee for commenting the same in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57426578/rsocket-server-exception-no-handler-for-destination-destination-does-not-pa